# How to use guake at right side monitor in dual display environment

Tags: command-line, guake

I want to use `Guake` at right monitor.

So I added this ppa by `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cberner/guake`, and `sudo apt-get update`.

https://launchpad.net/~cberner/+archive/guake/+index?field.series_filter=raring

Instruction says that I can set `monitor_index` somehow. But I couldn't find how to configure.

Does someone know about this?

Answer (score 21):

I use two monitors and wanted Guake to be displayed on the right one (where by default it is displayed on the left one).

What I did was to edit my `/usr/bin/guake/` file replacing the `get_final_window_rect` method with this:

```
def get_final_window_rect(self):
    """Gets the final size of the main window of guake. The height
    is the window_height property, width is window_width and the
    horizontal alignment is given by window_alignment.
    """
    screen = self.window.get_screen()
    height = self.client.get_int(KEY('/general/window_height'))
    width = 100
    halignment = self.client.get_int(KEY('/general/window_halignment'))

    # get the rectangle just from the first/default monitor in the
    # future we might create a field to select which monitor you
    # wanna use
    monitor = 1 # use the right most monitor
    window_rect = screen.get_monitor_geometry(monitor)
    # see if we don't have another screen, and if so, use the first one
    if window_rect.width == 0:
        monitor = 0
        window_rect = screen.get_monitor_geometry(monitor)
    total_width = window_rect.width
    window_rect.height = window_rect.height * height / 100
    window_rect.width = window_rect.width * width / 100

    if width < total_width:
        if halignment == ALIGN_CENTER:
            window_rect.x = (total_width - window_rect.width) / 2
            if monitor == 1:
                    right_window_rect = screen.get_monitor_geometry(0)
                    window_rect.x += right_window_rect.width
        elif halignment == ALIGN_LEFT:
            window_rect.x = 0
        elif halignment == ALIGN_RIGHT:
            window_rect.x = total_width - window_rect.width
    window_rect.y = 0
    return window_rect
```

Basically, it uses `1` as the monitor index and later on, adds the right screen width to the start point display of the guake window

hope this helps!

Comment: How did you open that file in order to edit it? I did it via xdg-open $file but it opens as read-only.

Comment: Any text editor will do, use `sudo` at the beginning of the command to have admin privileges

Comment: Oddly, this alternates between left and right every time I open it when I set 'Launcher placement' for the left monitor only. Setting it to the right one gets it to work every time.

Comment: It's true. Your comment made my install the latest version of Guake (from this ppa: `https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/unstable` and it seems that they've made it so now that you can choose between the  terminal appearing on the screen the mouse is at, or locking it to a specific screen, which I guess is a good enough solution in my opinion

Comment: @wilfo's comment identifying the updates from the original developers provides the simplest solution.  The built in features of Guake 0.7.2 add the ability to set the display as well as many other useful settings.

Comment: @rmobis, this sounds like a regression I just encountered in guake 3.4 that has been fixed in 3.5 https://github.com/Guake/guake/issues/1453

Answer (score 3):

Good news!

On version 0.8.5, Guake will be displayed on the active monitor,
so you don't have to tweak the Guake code anymore.

Comment: version 0.5.0 (the one in ubuntu repo) supports it as well: `apt-get install --only-upgrade guake`

Answer (score 2):

The solution is very simple, as you want to align your Guake screen to your right hand side monitor so in starting position (x, y) of screen, y co-ordinate is going to be same i.e. it will start from 0 but x coordinate will change and it should be equal to width of you left side monitor. To be able to do this you need to do 2 things.

I. Change monitor number to 1, as suggested above. In line

> window_rect = screen.get_monitor_geometry(0)

Replace 0 by 1.

II. Add first screen width in x position of starting co-ordinate. to do this.

Replace

```
if width < total_width:
    if halignment == ALIGN_CENTER:
        window_rect.x = (total_width - window_rect.width) / 2
    elif halignment == ALIGN_LEFT:
        window_rect.x = 0
    elif halignment == ALIGN_RIGHT:
        window_rect.x = total_width - window_rect.width
window_rect.y = 0
return window_rect
```

By

```
if width < total_width:
     if halignment == ALIGN_CENTER:
         window_rect.x += (total_width - window_rect.width) / 2
     elif halignment == ALIGN_LEFT:
         window_rect.x += 0
     elif halignment == ALIGN_RIGHT:
         window_rect.x += total_width - window_rect.width
window_rect.y = 0
return window_rect
```

Once you do these changes and restart guake (Quit and start again), You should get the desired alignment of Guake screen.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

I also made this a question: [guake at right side monitor in dual display environment - Ubuntu 15.10(Wily Werewolf))](https://askubuntu.com/questions/688915/guake-at-right-side-monitor-in-dual-display-environment-ubuntu-15-10wily-were)

In Ubuntu 15.10 guake has changed a little bit. To change your terminal to the right monitor you have to edit:

```
sudo vim /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/guake/guake_app.py
```

then change in line 831:

```
window_rect = screen.get_monitor_geometry(monitor)
```

by:

```
window_rect = screen.get_monitor_geometry(1)
```

kill and restart guake

Anyone knows a way to do this less hacky?

Answer (score 1):

As lalit said, the best way I found to do this on ubuntu 14.04LTS was changing

```
window_rect = screen.get_monitor_geometry(0)
```

to

```
window_rect = screen.get_monitor_geometry(0)
```

but changing

```
    if width < total_width:
    if halignment == ALIGN_CENTER:
        window_rect.x = (total_width - window_rect.width) / 2
    elif halignment == ALIGN_LEFT:
        window_rect.x = 0
    elif halignment == ALIGN_RIGHT:
        window_rect.x = total_width - window_rect.width
window_rect.y = 0
return window_rect
```

to

```
 if width < total_width:
     if halignment == ALIGN_CENTER:
         window_rect.x += total_width + (total_width - window_rect.width) / 2
     elif halignment == ALIGN_LEFT:
         window_rect.x += 0
     elif halignment == ALIGN_RIGHT:
         window_rect.x += total_width - window_rect.width
window_rect.y = 0
return window_rect
```

The only difference its in the first "if", without adding "total_width" to "window_rect.x" guake appears in the middle of my left monitor.

P.S: Sorry Lalit but I cannot add a comment to your post since I have no points yet =(

Comment: which file is that?

Comment: well this is really outdated, the package has changed, but it was one of the .py in the `/usr/lib/pythonXXX/dist-packages/guake/`. Probably `guake_app.py`

Answer (score 1):

The solution by wilfo doesn't work to me. In my case i solved on Linux Mint with the following code:

```
def get_final_window_rect(self):
    """Gets the final size of the main window of guake. The height
    is the window_height property, width is window_width and the
    horizontal alignment is given by window_alignment.
    """
    screen = self.window.get_screen()
    height = self.client.get_int(KEY('/general/window_height'))
    width = 100
    halignment = self.client.get_int(KEY('/general/window_halignment'))

    # future we might create a field to select which monitor you
    # wanna use
    #monitor = 0 # use the left most monitor
    monitor = screen.get_n_monitors() - 1 # use the right most monitor

    monitor_rect = screen.get_monitor_geometry(monitor)
    window_rect = monitor_rect.copy()
    window_rect.height = window_rect.height * height / 100
    window_rect.width = window_rect.width * width / 100

    if width < monitor_rect.width:
        if halignment == ALIGN_CENTER:
            window_rect.x = monitor_rect.x + (monitor_rect.width - window_rect.width) / 2
        elif halignment == ALIGN_LEFT:
            window_rect.x = monitor_rect.x
        elif halignment == ALIGN_RIGHT:
            window_rect.x = monitor_rect.x + monitor_rect.width - window_rect.width

    window_rect.y = monitor_rect.y
    return window_rect
```

I take it from [here](http://brightbyte.de/page/Guake_on_the_right_screen), but i changed `80` to `100`.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this but I think you can just edit /usr/bin/guake since it is a python script.

Find

`window_rect = screen.get_monitor_geometry(0)` #line 824 on my machine

and change the 0 to the index of the monitor you want guake to display in.

Comment: I edited the line `0` to `1` in `/usr/lib/guake/guake.py`. And restart guake, but nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to smartmouse and wilfo's answers, once you make the change to /usr/bin/guake you then have to to a hard restart. Logging out of the guake session does not end the Guake process.

Open system monitor and kill the guake application process then restart

Answer (score 0):

I had to change this on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with 2 monitors.

I was trying the above methods but realized the code had changed since.  I went into `~/.gconf/apps/guake/general` and edited `%gconf.xml` and changed `display_n (int)` from `0` to `1` for my 2nd monitor.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score -1):

I try in Ubuntu 14.04,
I found you just need to click "Preferences" at guake icon (right top screen) in either monitor, then click "Show" in the same monitor, then you can see guake terminal pop out at the monitor you are using !!!

Comment: It's not clear (at least to me) how this approach will "set monitor_index" Could you [edit] this answer to clarify how it answers the question? Thank you!