# guake at right side monitor in dual display environment - Ubuntu 15.10(Wily Werewolf))

Tags: guake, 15.10

Ok, This might be helpful to someone.

In Ubuntu 15.10 guake has changed a little bit. To change your terminal to the right monitor you have to edit:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/guake/guake_app.py
```

then change in line 831:

```
window_rect = screen.get_monitor_geometry(monitor)
```

by:

```
window_rect = screen.get_monitor_geometry(1)
```

kill and restart guake

Anyone knows a way to do this less hacky?

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Linux Mint and the following solution worked to me (it should work on Ubuntu as well).
Edit your /usr/bin/guake/ file replacing the `get_final_window_rect` method with this:

```
def get_final_window_rect(self):
    """Gets the final size of the main window of guake. The height
    is the window_height property, width is window_width and the
    horizontal alignment is given by window_alignment.
    """
    screen = self.window.get_screen()
    height = self.client.get_int(KEY('/general/window_height'))
    width = 100
    halignment = self.client.get_int(KEY('/general/window_halignment'))

    # future we might create a field to select which monitor you
    # wanna use
    #monitor = 0 # use the left most monitor
    monitor = screen.get_n_monitors() - 1 # use the right most monitor

    monitor_rect = screen.get_monitor_geometry(monitor)
    window_rect = monitor_rect.copy()
    window_rect.height = window_rect.height * height / 100
    window_rect.width = window_rect.width * width / 100

    if width < monitor_rect.width:
        if halignment == ALIGN_CENTER:
            window_rect.x = monitor_rect.x + (monitor_rect.width - window_rect.width) / 2
        elif halignment == ALIGN_LEFT:
            window_rect.x = monitor_rect.x
        elif halignment == ALIGN_RIGHT:
            window_rect.x = monitor_rect.x + monitor_rect.width - window_rect.width

    window_rect.y = monitor_rect.y
    return window_rect
```

I take it from [here](http://brightbyte.de/page/Guake_on_the_right_screen), but i changed `80` to `100`.